# CSS transforms, 2D as a fallback for 3D?

Tags: css, transform

This should be an easy answer, I just can't seem to find it via Google.

Does this CSS code cover me in case the user doesn't have 3D support?

```
transform: translate3d(-15px, -15px, 0) scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1);
transform: translate(-15px, -15px) scale(1.05, 1.05);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-15px, -15px, 0) scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1);
-webkit-transform: translate(-15px, -15px) scale(1.05, 1.05)
```

In other words, are the 2D versions ignored if 3D works?

Comment: In CSS, later statements have higer priority.

Comment: Yes, if anything it should be the other way around. Browsers are supposed to ignore declarations they can’t understand. So 2D first, so that it gets applied if the browser doesn’t “understand” the following `transform` declaration that tries to use 3D. Otherwise, for a browser that understands both, your second 2D `transform` would simply overwrite the first one for 3D.

Comment: @CBroe Can you post as an answer so I can throw points at you?

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, are the 2D versions ignored if 3D works

Not as you have currently written the properties – you need to reverse their order.

Browsers are supposed to ignore declarations they can’t understand.

So the 2D transforms should go first, so that they get applied if the browser doesn’t “understand” the following transform declaration that tries to use 3D. (Otherwise, for a browser that understands both, your second 2D transform would simply overwrite the first one for 3D.)